# ES6 deconstructing nested optional arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following ES6 code:

```
function foo({name, address: {street, postcode}}) {
  console.log(name, street, postcode);
}

foo({name: 'John', address: {street: 'Foo', postcode: 1234}});
foo({name: 'Bob'});
```

The first call works as expected. However, I would like to make `address` optional (`street` and `postcode` would be `undefined`) instead of throwing an error. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function foo({name, address: {street, postcode} = {}}) {
  console.log(name, street, postcode);
}
```

Comment: Yes, except the parentheses around `{}` are not required. Unfortunately, jshint still fails on this.

Comment: @torazaburo are you saying that jshint fails if the `()` are not present?

Comment: @torazaburo you should consider moving to eslint if you are using ES6.

Comment: No, I am saying that defaults in deconstructed argument lists (and assignments too) cause it to fail. Anyway, I have already moved. BTW nice question.